# Docker Postgres container not creating expected database

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I am launching a Postgres database via docker-compose, with...

```
Version: "3.7"
services:

  db:
    image: "postgres"
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: good_day
      POSTGRES_USER: ian
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ian
    volumes:
      - gd-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  gd-data:
```

When I login to the Postgres database from my 'DBeaver' db client,  I am not seeing a 'good_day' schema

**[image: strong text]**

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Solved it.

The problem is with 'DBeaver'...

The initial login for its postgres connector only seems to support 'postgres' as the database.

To see other databases requires that the 'Show all databases' option be enabled

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why this setting isn't on the Main tab and ticked by default